# Why do I get Template "@bartik/block" is not defined?

Tags: 8, theming

So I've created a small subtheme called `bartik_graphql`. It just overrides the 'Powered by Drupal' block. Besides it's `bartik_graphql.info.yml` file it has a `templates` directory containing one file `block--bartik-graphql-powered.html.twig`.

Contents of `block--bartik-graphql-powered.html.twig`:

```
{#graphql
query {
  admin:userById(id: "1") {
    name
  }
}
#}

{% extends "@bartik/block" %}

{% block content %}
  <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('content') }}>
    {{ content }} and some guy named {{ graphql.data.admin.name }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I've enabled my subtheme and set it to default. However I receive the following error:

> Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "@bartik/block" is not defined. in
>   Twig\Loader\ChainLoader->getCacheKey() (line 122 of
>   web/core/themes/bartik/templates/page.html.twig).

What I expect to happen is have my subtheme's template override what is used by default to display the 'Powered by Drupal' message.

Drupal: 8.7.8
PHP: 7.2.17

Am I using extends wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know of Twig namespacing just until now. But what always worked for
extends and includes is to point to the template you want to extend/include directly, with the path starting from Drupal web root. So in your case it needs to say:

```
{% extends "core/themes/bartik/templates/block.html.twig" %}
```

You could also try the following which seems to follow theme inheritance but only up to the final base theme (which would be Classy).

```
{% extends "@block/block.html.twig" %}
```

Comment: Thanks @leymannx that has appeared to do the trick. In my searches to find a solution I found similar suggestions but the particular example I was [looking at on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsmeXMZ0foM) showed him successfully using `{% extends @bartik/block" %}`. Could that perhaps be that the tutorial was from mid-2018 and that's no longer how it's done?

Comment: @frmt – Oh wow, I've never recognized Twig namespacing is actually used in a few places even in core. I just tried the same but for me it also doesn't work. Whereas Drupal root-relative paths work just fine...

Comment: It's even in the documentation in places like [GraphQL Twig](https://www.drupal.org/project/graphql_twig). I posted in their Slack channel about it, hopefully I can gain some more insight as to what they are doing.

Comment: @frmt – Can you tell me what happens when you put `{% extends "@block/block.html.twig" %}`. I wonder if it takes Bartik's or Classy's block then or if it still errors out as Classy (which Bartik is a sub-theme of) has no templates/block.html.twig but only a templates/block/block.html.twig.

Comment: Will do. Once I get back in the office in the morning I'll try that out and update you. There is a similar issue I'm having related to the same webinar on GraphQL Twig, so I also commented on that issue. It hasn't been addressed in three months so hopefully pinging it again will bring it to the forefront again.

Comment: Here is an update @leymannx. `@block/block.html.twig` works too, although the resulting output is minimal, I'm assuming Classy is pretty bare bones. When using your original suggestion I get a lot of stuff inherited from Bartik.

Comment: @frmt – Thank you! What I suggested, it goes up then until the final parent. I subscribed to mentioned issue on GitHub. As well still have no answer to why that happens.