# Extend twig template from differnt theme (parent)

Tags: theming

I created a sub theme of the bootstrap theme. In one of my twig-files I would like to extend a twig template from the parent like this:

```
{% extends '@bootstrap/menu/main--main.html.twig' %}
```

This doesn't work and I'm getting the message that main--main.html.twig is not defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get Template "@bartik/block" is not defined?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287299/why-do-i-get-template-bartik-block-is-not-defined)

Comment: What happens when you leave the `.html.twig` file ending out? Otherwise try the solution from the possible duplicate.